# Wordpress - Video in the bottom right corner

Tags: wordpress

I would like to add a fixed video in the bottom right corner of every page on my Wordpress website, but i was not able to find how. (It should be a small video in bottom right corner both on desktop and mobile version.)
Is there any plugin to help me with this task?

I tried using elementor with essential addons, but it only works on mobile, and it iterferes with the current layout i have set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try adding a video widget in your footer?

If you want it displayed as floating (absolute or fixed position), then just add a widget anywhere in your page content. Then use css to display the video (absolute or fixed position)

Sample code:

```
<div class="video-wrapper">
   <div class="video-content">
      Your video code or widget
   </div>
</div>
```

Use css to display the video as floating on right bottom corner.

```
.video-wrapper {
   position: relative;
}

.video-content {
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, i apologize for the late response. Your suggestion helped me achieve the said task. Thank you!